# How to create a tabular legend in ArcMap 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, legend

I want to create a legend in ArcMap 9.3 like the image below for a polygon layer. How can I do that?

[image]

The values in the first column (Molid, Brad, etc.) and in the second row of legend (1-40, 41-90, >80) are stored in two different attributes of the polygon layer. The text "categoria de vârstă (ani)" is the title of the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you will be able to use an ArcMap legend element to do this.

However, I think you could use [graphic elements](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=426&pid=422&topicname=Working_with_graphic_elements,_pictures,_and_neatlines) and [text elements](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Adding_new_text_to_a_map) to construct the appearance of a legend like you illustrated.

If you change the classification of your polygons those changes will not be automatically reflected in a static "legend" created in this way.

If you were using ArcGIS 10.0 or later, especially 10.1 SP1 or later, then arcpy.mapping would enable this to be largely automated.